# Debian ethernet interface goes down while streaming video

Tags: debian, ethernet, streaming, video

While streaming video FROM a debian box to the rest of a network, I regularly see the ethernet interface go down on this box after a couple hours of streaming and it doesn't come back up until the box is rebooted. It's very mysterious in that there is not output to even indicate what is happening. I did a tcpdump and checked it out in wireshark, nothing seems out of the ordinary, last frame sent was a udp packet of video.

I have a theory that it has something to do with spanning-tree, but it isn't based on much. Just that I see these packets coming in over wireshark.

I also had a theory about this being caused by flow control issues. Flow control is now completely disabled on the box, but the problem still continues.

Is there anything that could be blocking this ethernet? Maybe some sort of weird setting in Debian?

Any tips to help debug this would be great.

Comment: Do you have managed switches?  If so do the logs for that switchport show anything?  Its unlikely to be spanning tree problems, but if it is that is where you will see the evidence.

Comment: hardware problems? Did you try to replace that NIC? Other heavy traffic, othre than streaming video?

Comment: We do have managed switches, I will attempt to check the logs there, not sure I will be able to get access though.

Comment: I don't think it is a HW issue since we have a couple of these boxes that all exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Pot a completely different, good quality NIC into the system.

Comment: That's something I can try.  We are trying to use the integrated NIC though.